# Translation of "then"

Tags: перевод

I am wondering how you translate the word "then" as it is used in the following sentences.

1. If he can do it, **then** I can do it, too.
2. If you don't like this place, **then** why are you here?

Comment: тогда, in both cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We say тогда in both sentences. Or you can use *то* instead

> Если он может это делать, тогда(то) и я смогу тоже. Если тебе не нравится это место,тогда (то) почему ты здесь?

Comment: Why is и used in the first example? Also, is there a preferred one for certain formalities?

Comment: We usually add *и* with *тоже*, for instance in "So do I (me too)--И я тоже. As if you join the first person. I can see no difference in usage honestly .Perhaps тогда is slightly more formal.

Comment: if you wish to sound more categorical and resolved `и` can be dispensed with

Comment: I'd change the first sentence to "Если он может это сделать, то и я смогу". "тоже" seems to be excessive here.